# How can I configure the Code Coverage reports in Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I've been running my code coverage reports on my Android project using Gradle at the command-line, using the following command:

```
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

This works, and produces a report that contains pretty much every package in my entire project, including third-party libraries. I'd like to configure the coverage reports to provide information about only my code. How do I set up the code paths, includes and excludes on the Jacoco reports in the built-in coverage reports being produced by the Android Studio toolchain?

I am not including any Jacoco plugins within my build scripts, I have simply added `testCoverageEnabled true` in my debug buildType.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `createDebugCoverageReport` for just unit tests or android tests + unit tests?

Comment: I'd like to combine both, but at the moment just android tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You want to do the following:**

1. Run unit tests: `gradlew testDebug`
2. Run android tests: `gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest`
3. Create code coverage for Android tests: `gradlew createDebugCoverageReport`
4. After these steps, you can finally combine them using a single task

**Apply `testCoverageEnabled`:**

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

}
```

**Apply `includeNoLocationClasses`:**

```
android {

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Now you can create a task like this one:**

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec", 
            "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ])
}
```

**And run it:**

```
gradle clean jacocoTestReport
```

**Source:** https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa

Comment: Nice. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Definitely haven't gone in and tested this out yet. But I will need to very soon. Thanks for the reminder @jared-burrows.

Comment: Yes, this solves my needs perfectly. I just had to modify the dependencies of the task, because I only test on one of the flavors we have. But otherwise it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This config has been outdated. A new version from the same author can be found here: https://proandroiddev.com/unified-code-coverage-for-android-revisited-44789c9b722f

Comment: This worked thanks, except I had to change the directory for the `.ec` files to: `"outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*coverage.ec"`

Comment: report showing zero ... any suggestion for kotlin ?

Comment: Out of date and does not work with Kotlin